# Automatically insert prototype functions from .h with Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

How do I configure emacs to automatically insert prototype functions from .h when opening the corresponding .cc file?.

Comment: Erm, with a macro of course.  But I reckon you're really asking "who wrote a macro like that so I don't have to?"  I personally never left the *most* important job to a tool.  I'll go away now.

Comment: @Hans Passant: could you explain why it's a bad idea for a tool? I just don't want to retype the same function over and over again... Also if you know a useful macro could you direct me to the source? Maybe I can modify it a little to suit my needs.

Comment: @Mark - Guess Hans has an editor with cut and paste, so he doesn't have to type it twice.

Comment: @Bo Persson: well cut and paste is too cumbersome... I don't see why a text editor shouldn't provide this feature...

Comment: You're probably going to spend much more time creating macros or scripts to do this over just using copy & paste which would be the definition of cumbersome to me.

Comment: @AJG85: I have lots of free time, I must create more automation to write less tedious code, please understand :-)

Comment: @Mark: Of that I am envious. The only automation like this I've seen in action was using UML and IBM's Rational Rose, but it's not free or fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something like this that I used for doing this when I was doing more C++ coding, using the member-functions package:

```
(require 'member-function)

;;expand member functions automatically when entering a cpp file
(defun c-file-enter ()
  "Expands all member functions in the corresponding .h file"
  (let* ((c-file (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
         (h-file-list (list (concat (substring c-file 0 -3 ) "h")
                            (concat (substring c-file 0 -3 ) "hpp")
                            (concat (substring c-file 0 -1 ) "h")
                            (concat (substring c-file 0 -1 ) "hpp"))))
    (if (or (equal (substring c-file -2 ) ".c")
            (equal (substring c-file -4 ) ".cpp"))
        (mapcar (lambda (h-file)
                  (if (file-exists-p h-file)
                      (expand-member-functions h-file c-file)))
                h-file-list))))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook c-file-enter)
```

You can find member-functions.el at: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/member-functions.el

Comment: This looks promising. I will try it when I get back home.

Comment: I am having some trouble byte-compiling member-functions.el. Getting the error:  Symbol's value as variable is void: warning-suppress-types

Comment: got workaround simple insert   (setq warning-suppress-types nil)  into .emacs

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this hack a while back ... it's not great, but could be a starting point.  To use it, start in the `.cc` file where you want the function implementation inserted, switch to the `.h` file and go to the function definition, then `M-x my-c-make-function-from-prototype` (I have it bound to a key of course).

```
(require 'ffap)
(defun my-c-make-function-from-prototype ()
  "Turn a function prototype into a skeleton implementation."
  (interactive)
  (let (ret-val fcn-name args const namespaces start-of-fcn)
    (save-excursion
      (end-of-line)
      (c-beginning-of-statement 1)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (re-search-forward
             "\\s-*\\(.*\\)\\s-+\\([-a-zA-Z0-9_!=<>~]+\\)\\s-*[(]" nil t)
        (setq ret-val (match-string 1))
        (setq ret-val (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(virtual\\|static\\)\\s-*" "" ret-val))
        (setq fcn-name (match-string 2))
        (when (re-search-forward "\\([^)]*\\)[)]" nil t)
          (setq args (match-string 1))
          (setq args (replace-regexp-in-string "\\s-*=.+?," "," args))
          (setq args (replace-regexp-in-string "\\s-*=.+?)" ")" args))
          (setq args (replace-regexp-in-string "\\s-*=.+?$" "" args))
          (if (looking-at "\\s-*const")
              (setq const " const")
            (setq const ""))
          (condition-case nil
              (while 't
                (backward-up-list 1)
                (when (re-search-backward
                     "\\(class\\|namespace\\|struct\\)\\s-+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)" nil t)
                  (setq namespaces (concat (match-string 2) "::" namespaces))))
            (error nil)))))
    ;; Switch to other file and insert implementation
    (ff-get-other-file)
    (setq start-of-fcn (point))
    (insert (concat ret-val (unless (string= ret-val "") "\n") namespaces fcn-name "(" args ")" const))
    (insert "\n{\n/** @todo Fill in this function. */\n}\n")
    (unless (eobp)
      (insert "\n"))
    (indent-region start-of-fcn (point) nil)
    (goto-char start-of-fcn)
    (when (fboundp 'doxymacs-insert-function-comment)
      (doxymacs-insert-function-comment))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you can combine `autoinsert` package with CEDET's Senator "Copy tag", but this will require some elisp programming to open file, force parsing of it, and then iterating over *function* tags...

Although, if you want to copy entire .h, it will easier, although also will involve elisp - you need to insert empty file via `auto-insert` function, and then copy .h file content using action function that is second element in `auto-insert-alist` variable. Function will look something like:

```
 (defun my-auto-insert-h-content ()
   (when buffer-file-name
     (let ((h-filename (concat (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) ".h")))
       (when (file-exists-p h-filename)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (insert-file-contents h-filename)))))
```

Comment: Could you give me some more hints on how to do the first part? I have used lisp before, so I don't mind writing macros...

Comment: look onto my config at https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-auto-insert.el - you need to provide mapping of file mask to cons, consisting of template file (my are in https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master/auto-insert), and function, that will executed after template file is inserted into new file...